# Why "google-chrome" does not run chrome?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome

I try to open `Google Chrome` by running this command, but the result is strange:

```
$ google-chrome
Please launch slimjet via the wrapper script: flashpeak-slimjet
```

Why above command does not open `Google Chrome` and also  what is the meaning of above result?

Edit:

Here is the result of `which` command:

```
$ which google-chrome
/usr/bin/google-chrome
```

Also, `/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome` and `google-chrome-stable` both open `Google Chrome`. But again, my questions are why `google-chrome` does not?and why `flashpeak-slimjet` is proposed?

Comment: Try `/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --enable-plugins`

Comment: @Liso But I do not want to enable plugins.

Comment: Remove `--enable-plugins` option then

Comment: @Liso OK! But why `$ google-chrome` does not work?

Comment: Run this command and post the answer: `which google-chrome`

Comment: Try `google-chrome-stable`.

Comment: @Parto I added result of `which` command to question, please see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command to start Google Chrome is `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable`, or just `google-chrome-stable` if `/usr/bin` is in the PATH as it should. In general, to see what is the command to run a graphical application, use Nautilus to navigate to `/usr/share/applications` and examine the properties of the launcher, or, in a terminal, look for the line `Exec=` in the `.desktop` file.

Answer (score 1):

It's a mess the installer of slimjet, a chromium-based browser (looks pretty much identical, that's probably what you're running sometimes), does in your system, replacing the actual chrome's symlink.

Answer (score 0):

It's a hijack by slimjet. In `/etc/alternatives/`, for each `google-chrome`, `gnome-www-browser`, and `x-www-browser`, change the symlink to `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable`, e.g.:

```
sudo ln -f -s /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable /etc/alternatives/google-chrome
```